# Question: Expansion of algebra in matrices

Tags: matrices

I have a problem that I would like to check:

> Expand $(A+B)^3$ where $A$ and $B$ are matrices.

Is this right?
$$
A^3+A^2B+ABA+AB^2+BA^2+BAB+B^2A+B^3
$$
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you've got it.

It is probably easiest to start off with
$$
(A+B)^2=A(A+B)+B(A+B)=A^2+AB+BA+B^2.
$$
From here, we find
$$
(A+B)^3=(A+B)(A^2+AB+BA+B^2)=A^3+A^2B+ABA+AB^2+BA^2+BAB+B^2A+B^3,
$$
as you claimed.